# javascript add text to youtube description box

Tags: javascript

am trying to add text to youtube description box.
here is the javascirpt code am using but not inputting the text as i am sure am not doing it right.

```
x=document.getElementsByClassName("description-textarea");
for(var i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
    x[i].innerText="text 1 changed!";    // Change the content
    }
```

here is some code i got from html element

```
<div id="outer" class="style-scope ytcp-form-input-container"><div id="label" class="style-scope ytcp-form-input-container">
      Description
      <div id="label-help-tooltip" class="style-scope ytcp-form-input-container"><tp-yt-iron-icon id="help-icon" class="help-outline-icon style-scope ytcp-form-input-container" compact="" tabindex="0" aria-labelledby="goog_929542190" role="tooltip"><svg viewBox="0 0 24 24" preserveAspectRatio="xMidYMid meet" focusable="false" class="style-scope tp-yt-iron-icon" style="pointer-events: none; display: block; width: 100%; height: 100%;"><g class="style-scope tp-yt-iron-icon"><path d="M11 18h2v-2h-2v2zm1-16C6.48 2 2 6.48 2 12s4.48 10 10 10 10-4.48 10-10S17.52 2 12 2zm0 18c-4.41 0-8-3.59-8-8s3.59-8 8-8 8 3.59 8 8-3.59 8-8 8zm0-14c-2.21 0-4 1.79-4 4h2c0-1.1.9-2 2-2s2 .9 2 2c0 2-3 1.75-3 5h2c0-2.25 3-2.5 3-5 0-2.21-1.79-4-4-4z" class="style-scope tp-yt-iron-icon"></path></g></svg><!--css_build_mark:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_iron_icon.tp.yt.iron.icon.css.js--><!--css_build_scope:tp-yt-iron-icon--><!--css_build_styles:third_party.javascript.youtube_components.tp_yt_iron_icon.tp.yt.iron.icon.css.js-->
</tp-yt-iron-icon><ytcp-paper-tooltip for="help-icon" position="top" type="explanatory" class="style-scope ytcp-form-input-container"><!--css_build_mark:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp.paper.tooltip.css.js--><!--css-build:shady--><!--css_build_scope:ytcp-paper-tooltip--><!--css_build_styles:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.shared.ui.styles.yt_base_styles.yt.base.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.styles.ytcp_styles.ytcp.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp.paper.tooltip.css.js-->
<ytcp-paper-tooltip-placeholder role="tooltip" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip" disable-upgrade="" id="goog_929542190">
  <div id="slot-wrapper" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip"></div>
  <div id="tooltip-placeholder-fake-slot" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip"><ytcp-paper-tooltip-body class="style-scope ytcp-form-input-container"><!--css_build_mark:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp_paper_tooltip_body.ytcp.paper.tooltip.body.css.js--><!--css-build:shady--><!--css_build_scope:ytcp-paper-tooltip-body--><!--css_build_styles:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.shared.ui.styles.yt_base_styles.yt.base.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.styles.ytcp_styles.ytcp.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_paper_tooltip.ytcp_paper_tooltip_body.ytcp.paper.tooltip.body.css.js-->
  <p class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body"><yt-formatted-string class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body">Writing descriptions with keywords can help viewers to find your videos more easily through search. You can give an overview of your video and place keywords at the beginning of the description.</yt-formatted-string></p>
<dom-repeat as="p" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body"></dom-repeat>
<dom-repeat as="message" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body"></dom-repeat>



  <p class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body">
    <ytcp-anchor class="link style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body"><!--css_build_mark:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_anchor.ytcp.anchor.css.js--><!--css-build:shady--><!--css_build_scope:ytcp-anchor--><!--css_build_styles:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.shared.ui.styles.yt_base_styles.yt.base.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.styles.ytcp_styles.ytcp.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.ytcp_anchor.ytcp.anchor.css.js--><a id="anchor" class="remove-default-style style-scope ytcp-anchor" href="https://creatoracademy.youtube.com/page/lesson/descriptions" target="_blank">
  <dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-anchor"></dom-if>
  <span class="text style-scope ytcp-anchor">
    
    
    
    Learn more
  </span>
  <dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-anchor"></dom-if>
</a>
</ytcp-anchor>
  </p>
<dom-repeat as="link" class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip-body"></dom-repeat>
</ytcp-paper-tooltip-body></div>
  <dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-paper-tooltip"></dom-if>
</ytcp-paper-tooltip-placeholder>
</ytcp-paper-tooltip></div><dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-form-input-container"></dom-if></div><dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-form-input-container"></dom-if><div id="child-input" class="style-scope ytcp-form-input-container"><div slot="body" id="container-content" class="style-scope ytcp-social-suggestions-textbox">
    <ytcp-social-suggestion-input id="input" class="fill-height style-scope ytcp-social-suggestions-textbox"><!--css_build_mark:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.social_suggestions.ytcp_social_suggestion_input.ytcp.social.suggestion.input.css.js--><!--css-build:shady--><!--css_build_scope:ytcp-social-suggestion-input--><!--css_build_styles:video.youtube.src.web.polymer.shared.ui.styles.yt_base_styles.yt.base.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.styles.ytcp_styles.ytcp.styles.css.js,video.youtube.src.web.polymer.creator_studio.shared.widgets.social_suggestions.ytcp_social_suggestion_input.ytcp.social.suggestion.input.css.js--><div id="textbox" slot="input" contenteditable="true" class="style-scope ytcp-social-suggestions-textbox" aria-required="false" aria-label="Tell viewers about your video (type @ to mention a channel)" aria-invalid="false"></div>
</ytcp-social-suggestion-input>
    <div class="container-bottom style-scope ytcp-social-suggestions-textbox">
      <dom-if class="style-scope ytcp-social-suggestions-textbox"></dom-if>

      <div class="char-counter style-scope ytcp-social-suggestions-textbox">0/5000</div>
    </div>
  </div></div></div>
```

Comment: Why you have used the class `description-textarea`?  It is not the class of any element.

Comment: i want to add my own string into the description box

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### Description Box

Use the `CSS` selector `#textbox[aria-label="Tell viewers about your video (type @ to mention a channel)"`. An HTML page should have only a single `id` attribute. But, since, there are multiple elements with id `textbox`. Therefore, we have also to specify some other attributes. I used `aria-label` here.

The complete code for updating the description will be:

```js
let descriptionElement = document.querySelector('#textbox[aria-label="Tell viewers about your video (type @ to mention a channel)"]');
descriptionElement.textContent = 'This is the updated description text';
```

#### Title

If you also want to update the `title`, you can do that as:

```js
let titleElement = document.getElementById('textbox');
titleElement.textContent = 'updated title'
```

#### Tags

For updating the tags, Use the following script:

```js
let tagsElement = document.querySelector('#text-input[aria-label="Tags"]');

let string = 'hello,world'; // comma-separated tags
let tags = string.split(',');

// alternatively, you can initilize tags as 
// let tags = ['hello', 'world'];

tags.forEach(tag => {
    tagsElement.value = tag;
    tagsElement.dispatchEvent(new KeyboardEvent('keyup', {key: ','}));
});
```

Comment: omg wow. your the best of the best i love you.  bro can you do one for ( title ) and  ( tags ) and il test and mark as resolved

Comment: I'm glad that it helped. If you want to include `title` and `tags` too. So, update the question (and title) also.

Comment: trying for title not working        '#textbox[aria-label="Add a title that describes your video (type @ to mention a channel)"]'

Comment: ok i done it.   one more thing when adding the text to the textbox of youtube how do i add another code so that the red text goes away making youtube textbox think its been clicked or text been added manually

Comment: I don't think there's any red line. I have checked it.

Comment: let text-inputElement = document.querySelector(
    '#textbox[aria-label="Add tag"]'
     );

text-inputElement.textContent = 'This is the updated description text';       not working can you add 2 tags and confirm it adds it as it should

Comment: not doing it for some reason. am still testing bare me

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/248838/discussion-between-muhammad-khuzaima-umair-and-hans).

Comment: ok it works. seems like i need to go to the main menu and go back into editing mode and it lets me add it not sure why it dont work. it requires me to go out of the editor and come back in to re-set it

Comment: i can accept this unless you have another code that dont require me to exit editor and come back in?

Comment: if i may also show u a quick video of the red text hold on

Comment: i used your code for title but this seems shorter  document.getElementById("textbox").innerText = "message";  how do i add a javascript code to add 1 space after that execution

Answer (score 0):

```
let descriptionElement = document.querySelector('#textbox[aria-label="Tell viewers about your video (type @ to mention a channel)"]');
descriptionElement.textContent = 'This is the updated description text';
```

Credit to @Muhammad Khuzaima Umair